# Error no such file or directory when build openssl in ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, aes

I'm working on a Android project which using AES encryption to encrypt and decrypt files. But the built-in Cipher in Java is really slow. After doing some research, I decided to use NDK to build a wrapper for aes in OpenSSL library. So I created an Android project:

Android project structure:

```
src
res
jni
    openssl-1.0.1e (openssl source code folder)
    Android.mk

    wrapper-folder
        aes_wrapper.c
        Android.mk
        Application.mk
```

First my aes_wrapper.c has a function very simple and ndk-build successfully. But when I tried to write encrypt function I include "../openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/aes/aes.h" to aes_wrapper.c, I got the error below:

```
openssl/opensslconf.h no such file or directory
```

The header file opensslconf.h is located in ../openssl-1.0.1e/include/openssl

Can anyone show me how to figure it out? Thanks a ton and sorry about my poor English.

**EDIT**: Here are Android.mk

1. In folder openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/aes

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE := libaes

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes_cbc.c aes_cfb.c aes_core.c aes_ctr.c aes_ebc.c aes_ige.c         aes_misc.c aes_ofb.c aes_wrap.c aes_x86core.c

   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
   ```
2. In folder wrapper

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := aes_wrapper
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes_wrapper.c
   LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz -ljnigraphics

   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libaes

   LOCAL_IS_SUPPORT_LOG := true
   ifeq ($(LOCAL_IS_SUPPORT_LOG),true)
   LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
   endif

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

Comment: Do you include the header directory in your Android.mk? Posting your Android.mk could really help.

Comment: @user2359247 I have added 2 Android.mk. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the header files in your Android.mk under the appropriate module as follows:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /path/to/openssl-1.0.1e
```

In this case, I think jni/openssl-1.0.1e should suffice. The final appearance of the module should look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := aes_wrapper 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes_wrapper.c 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/openssl-1.0.1e 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libaes

LOCAL_IS_SUPPORT_LOG := true 
ifeq ($(LOCAL_IS_SUPPORT_LOG),true) 
  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Your suggestion is very useful. At least, I have keyword now to figure out the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again. I have fixed it out. Now it's time for wrapper.